# CSS: background-position + padding not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I added a background image to a textfield and positioned it using `background-position` (direction padding direction padding, Ex: right 10px top 10px). It's looks good in all browsers except Safari. In safari the background image is positioned top left without any padding. If I add `background-position` (padding padding, Ex: 144px 10px;) without specifying position works fine, but I need to make it work the first way I mentioned.

This is the code that is not working on Safari:

`background-position: right 10px top 10px;`

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xEZfM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this previous question, it will probably answer your question - [CSS3 background-position issue with Safari only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542051/css3-background-position-issue-with-safari-only)  For future reference, make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem, so we can try to fix it ourselves before just giving you educated guesses.

Comment: I saw that question before asking this but it's not working for me.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xEZfM/

Comment: I just tried doing what that question suggested and it seemed to work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/xEZfM/2/

Comment: I understood wrong what that question suggested. It works for me to now. Sorry and thank you!