# How to set Circle image?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

How can i display circle image from rectangular image using bootstrap?

Here is may code for circle;

```
<img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" >
```

But it is work for only Square images, For Rectangular image it will become eclipse. How Can we resolve it without giving fix height or width?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v5e5X/

Comment: Maybe this article about masking/clipping points you to a good direction? -> https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: Use `border-radius`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: Using img-circle, how to get circle from non-square image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852978/bootstrap-3-using-img-circle-how-to-get-circle-from-non-square-image)

Comment: use css property border-radius:50px;

Comment: Giving border-radius simply won't work. See the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  border-radius not working for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by giving the image as background from this answer - 
[Bootstrap 3: Using img-circle, how to get circle from non-square image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852978/bootstrap-3-using-img-circle-how-to-get-circle-from-non-square-image)

Well, **If you still want to use `Img` tag to display the image** then, I found the solution in a weird way.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7xf03fa/)**

```css
div.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.clipped-image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.clipped-image {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* desired width */
}

.clipped-image:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}

.clipped-image .mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>Original image</h4>
  <div class="real-image">
    <img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240">
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <h4>Image after clipping</h4>
  <div class="clipped-image">
    <div class="mask">
      <img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KinjalGohil Though its hack, I'm strongly recommend you to set image as background as I mentioned in the first sentence. If your problem is solved, please mark this answer as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body class="w3-container">

<h2>Image in a Circle</h2>
<p>You do not need boostrap, you can use w3-schools libraries instead</p>

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/lGq1IXo.png" class="w3-circle" alt="" style="width:50%">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution and edited it so you can just change the size of the canvas and the image will still align. The `x_move` and `y_move` variables determine which part of the image is shown

```js
var myImage = new Image();
var size = myCanvas.width;
var x_move = -35;
var y_move = 0;

function displayImage() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    myImage.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(myImage, x_move, y_move, (myImage.width / (myImage.height / size)) , size );
      ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
      ctx.lineWidth = (size/2).toString();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(size/2, size/2, size*0.75, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    myImage.src = "https://i1.wp.com/nypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/09/astley1_index1a.jpg";

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="displayImage()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200">
    </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Original Code: 
https://www.authorcode.com/show-image-into-a-circle-shape-in-html5/

Answer (score -1):

This can be simply achieved by doing:
Add a class to your image just like this:

```css
.rounded {
  flex: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="rounded" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145922/preview2/eb6591b54b2b6462b4c22ec1fc4c36ea-female-avatar-maker.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. This CSS renders an ellipse for rectangular images, and that's exactly the issue the OP is trying to circumvent